# Stacked div's, z-index and a box-shadow on pseudo element

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't figure out why the box-shadow I try to apply on a headline element is not rendered properly in Firefox.

Here is the living example:
http://dev.longbeachrecords.de/bands/nh3-2/

The shadow works fine on the right side and on the content parts on the left but strangely not for the headline element.

I hope someone can put me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: more about the question please

Comment: I have three div's stacked on top of each other and a box-shadow applied to its :before pseudo element giving it more depth and that stacked look.Now for some reason the shadow applied to the headline is not rendered correcly. Is this whole things maybe not working because I use several z-index's?  @LIJINSAMUEL

Comment: NH3 heading right?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Not only is the website including many different stylesheets, which makes it pretty hard to debug, but as it is the live site, it may probably change as we speak, making it a moving target.

Comment: exactly @LIJINSAMUEL. I will also try to show the problem in a codepen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [you have some critical errors](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.longbeachrecords.de%2Fbands%2Fnh3-2%2F). Browsers nowadays try to correct them but the outcome is not necessarily the one you expect what makes finding css errors slightly harder so keep an eye on proper code validation.

As for your problem, here's the solution...

Add this:

```
.entry-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

as this element should be above *div.page-header-image-single* which has **z-index: 20**.
Then delete **z-index: 51** property from **h1.entry-title, h1.page-title**

Don't forget to uncomment *h1.entry-title:before,h1.page-title:before* in your style.css:124

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, Sharak. I'm gonna check your solution ASAP. Cheers!